# How do I Implement Different HTML Code for Specific Screen Sizes? (without Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css

So, I am currently attempting to make my webpage change format according to the screen width of the device it is viewed on. I have two separate projects, one specifically formatted for [mobile screens](https://codepen.io/gracethelittleartist/pen/WEByNy?editors=1100) and one specifically for [desktop/tablet screens](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxdVdO?editors=1100).

The problem with having only CSS changes (using the @media query) is that not only is the search input in different locations (desktop it is in the last li tag, for mobile it is the first li tag), but also the checkbox input that makes the mobile drop-down work is messing up the desktop/tablet version when I try to use the same html code for both using the mobile html code (hovering doesn't work correctly). Is there a method (other than Bootstrap) for me to specify or change these html code differences on my header so it will switch from one to another based off of a specific width that I can state (basically @media query but for html too)?  Or is there another option?

Here is the HTML code for my mobile version:

```
<div class="wrap">
<span class="decor"></span>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary" class="sub">
        <li class="search"> 
              <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform"> 
        <img id="search-icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/mObvmk/search.png">
        <input  class="search-input" type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Search..." /> 
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" id="search-btn" /> 
      </form>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
    <li class="ul-li">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="#" >Art <img height="10" class="dropdown-icon" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows//expand_arrow1600.png" alt=""></a>
      <ul class="ul-li-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Drawing Academy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2009-2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cartoons</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li class="ul-li"> <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Handcrafted <img height="10" class="dropdown-icon" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows//expand_arrow1600.png" alt=""></a>
       <ul class="ul-li-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry Making</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skin Care</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    <li><a href="#">Literature</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Here is code for my desktop version:

```
<div class="wrap">
<span class="decor"></span>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary" class="sub">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
    <li class="ul-li">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="#" >Art <img height="10" class="dropdown-icon" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows//expand_arrow1600.png" alt=""></a>
      <ul class="ul-li-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Drawing Academy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2009-2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cartoons</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li class="ul-li"> <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Handcrafted <img height="10" class="dropdown-icon" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows//expand_arrow1600.png" alt=""></a>
       <ul class="ul-li-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Jewelry Making</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skin Care</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    <li><a href="#">Literature</a></li>
        <li class="search"> 
              <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform"> 
        <img id="search-icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/mObvmk/search.png">
        <input  class="search-input" type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Search..." /> 
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" id="search-btn" /> 
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just put in both the html and set diplay to none for the one that shouldnt be displayed using media queries.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the HTML. You can relocate elements using flexbox or javascript. Someone with more time may give you such a solution.

Comment: Serve two different documents on two different addresses and put a redirect for mobiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mob{
    display:none;
}
.desk{
    display:block
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .desk{
        display:none;
    }
   .mob{
       display:block;
   }
}
```

Sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8z3dqnr/3/)..

Comment: Um...thank you for the answer, but could you update your fiddle so that it also solves the checkbox problem?  (Mobile has input check box in li tags, desktop does not). Thanks for the answer, and I'm well aware that I can apply the same technique for this, but this would improve your answer and I can then mark it official.

Comment: Yep!  That's perfect! Answer accepted, thank you. Just remember to update your answer with the new jsfiddle link.

Comment: and I made another changes in the checkbox.. and I updated the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: You see, I was hiding the checkbox because I needed it for the toggle-click dropdown animation but not for the looks because it wasn't a checkbox menu, it was a normal webpage menu. That's fine, it's nothing. I can change it myself. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153832/discussion-between-grace-sawyer-and-shadow-fiend).